# Disk usage of a file with specific extension

Tags: shell, sh

I want to log disk usage of all rpm files in a folder . The following script is listing out diskusage of files with .rpm extension.

```
for name in $(find . -type d -maxdepth 1)
do
dirname=$(basename "$name")
du -a $dirname/*.rpm 
done
```

However, if an innerfolder doesn't contain an .rpm file, then I am getting an error message

> "du: cannot access `err/*.rpm': No such file or directory" .

I wan't to avoid this error message. I tried grep -v and checking for file extension condition as follows.

```
for name in $(find . -type d -maxdepth 1)

do
  dirname=$(basename "$name")
  count=`ls -1 dirname *.rpm 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
  if [ $count != 0 ]; then
  echo $count;  
  du -a $dirname/*.rpm 
  fi
done
```

However, am not able to avoid the error message. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.Thanks in Advance. PFA of image too.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find . -regex '.*\.rpm' -print0 | du --files0-from=- -a`

- The `-print0` option for `find` and `--files0-from` for `du` are there to avoid issues with whitespace in file names
- The regular expression is matched against the whole path, e.g. `./dir1/subdir2/rpm1.rpm`, not just `rpm1.rpm`, so if you modify it, take that into account

Comment: How can I search .rpm files recursively in  folders whose folder-name starts with xyz.

Comment: Don't pile on additional requirements in comments; ask a new question. But in brief, the `-path` predicate allows you to add a constraint on the pathname (though it's slightly unwieldy; try `-path */xyz*' -not -name 'xyz*'` but this still matches any parent directory. GNU `find` has additional predicates which are more flexible).

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `find` here since you are just getting sub-directories in current directory.

You can just use this simple `for` loop:

```
for f in */*.rpm; do
   du -a "$f"
done
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.This doesn't do recursive listing. I mean if an x folder contains two rpm files and a y folder with an rpm file, this doesn't work

Comment: It will find `*.rpm` files in all the sub-directories of the current directory. What shell are you using?

Comment: Use `*/*.rpm */*/*.rpm` to go up to two folders deep.

Comment: I checked in gash bash and in ubuntu terminal, the error message is coming too.

Comment: You don't need the `for` loop, either.  `du -a *.rpm */*.rpm */*/*.rpm`

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this in a very roundabout way.

As @anubhava points out, you don't really need `find` in your particular scenario if you only care about immediate subdirectories of the current directory, or only two levels deep.

If you wanted to find all `*.rpm` files in all subdirectories to arbitrary levels of nesting, I would use `find` directly.  Use `%b` instead of `%k` if you want 512-byte blocks.

```
find . -name '*.rpm' -printf '%k\n' | awk '{s+=1} END { print s }'
```

If you want to see each individual file along with the disk space it uses,

```
find . -name '*.rpm' -printf '%k %p\n'
```

Comment: Hi, This command will return count. I want to list rpm files with space(du).

Comment: No, it's the sum of the disk space used by the matched files.  Try it with `printf '%n %k\n'` and without the Awk pipe to see what it does.

Comment: I want to list files and the diskspace used individually..If i remove pipe, it list file sizes without file name

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean; but I updated the answer to hopefully at least nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Ooops, my bad, `%p` not `%n`.

Comment: What operator I have to use If I want to list file sizes in mega bytes

Comment: There is no built-in for that, as [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) will readily reveal.  Divide by 1,024.

Comment: thanks for reply. adding human readable format -h to spirtuals answer gave the solution.

Comment: adding to your vibe, total size in blocks and count of files:  find . -name '*.rpm' -printf '%k\n' | awk '{t+=$k;s+=1} END { print t" "s }'